# Call to a member function parameter() on a non-object in Lumen API

Tags: api, lumen

I got this error in my Lumen API update user module. I didn't get the Request `$request` values from postman. It's happening only in my `UserController`,
my other controllers work fine. I'm using the `put` method to update the user.

This is the error:

> FatalErrorException in Request.php line 901: Call to a member function
>   parameter() on a non-object in Lumen API

My update function looks like this:

```
public function updateUser(Request $request,$user_id)
{
    try {
        $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);

    } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {

        return "User not found";
    }
    $user->buyer_id = $request->buyer_id;
```

Answer (score 11):

The thing is, Lumen and Laravel use different route resolvers. You can see it for yourself if you just output the type of the variable `$route` just before that line 901.

Try `$request['buyer_id']` instead.

Comment: Thank you dear.. I solved this issue using input function with request..    like $request->input('buyer_id')... like that...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `$request->input('buyer_id');` instead which would not throw any error if the `buyer_id` doesn't exist on $request stack (if it helps).

We can also pass the default value like this:
`$request->input('buyer_id', null);`